# Where can I get information about iOS file handlers for VOIP apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, voip

I have an iOS app that makes phone calls using the Telephone application by using a `tel://` file handler. I'm looking for the file handler for VoIP applications so my app can work on iPad and iPod touch. Where can I find out the file handler for Skype and other VoIP apps?

(I assume Skype is `skype://`... What about Fring? Google Voice?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a simpler way than downloading these apps from iTunes, unzipping the .ipa file, and looking into their Info.plist for their CFBundleURLTypes.

Comment: Good suggestion! I'm not sure if the PLIST is binary or not, though. I'll look into it.

Comment: Can you please update with your findings? I have the same question

Comment: @uniquesnowflake8 - sure. I basically searched the app store for VoIP apps. Indeed the only way to get this info is to search the Plist files manually.